# Object pooling: howto

Tags: java, pooling, object-pooling

I need to implement a pool of Sessions that are returned by an external system,
so that I can reuse them quickly as soon as one is needed (creating a Session takes a while).
I've worked with datasource to create a pool of database connections (DBCP from Apache), and it was
an implemented solution.

What do we use in a general case to pool arbitrary objects, and are there implemented solutions, ie objects, not interfaces, to deal with the task painfully?

Second question would be, how do we test whether the Session is alive ? Is there a specific method that we override in the Object pool, that queries the Session's own methods?

The third, VERY IMPORTANT question, would be, should that object pooling object **be static**? A bundle of objects I extract from the system must be shared among different web applications. So, say, we extract 5 Sessions. App A queries the POOL and gets the first available Session. Now there are 4 Sessions left. Another App B starts and queries THE SAME POOL. etc The pool is shared. Among different instances of the same web app, running on the same machine.

Comment: If you're already familiar with Commons DBCP, then this is based on Commons Pool, which is a general purpose object pooling library.

Comment: @skaffman That may be, but here I see only a few implementations that do nothing http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/package-summary.html That's not enough to get it worked. Is there something more specific?

Comment: You need to extend `BaseObjectPool`, which is easy enough. You need to do *some* work...

Comment: So I need to create my own data structure, and override addObject/returnObject to hold stuff in my structure? That's the way to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a generic pool of objects,
   you have an [Apache Commons
   project](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) for that.
2. For testing
   that a session is alive, there are
   different ways, but many of them are
   unreliable. And the reliable one
   (doing a query on `dual`) is slow.
   You can have a look at [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0),
   which has that feature built-in.
3. As long as your many webapps are in the same WAR file, I think you'd be OK to use this static pool object. Although, personally, I prefer singletons over static objects that have anything more than utility methods and constants.

In general, I'm a big fan of `Hibernate`... have you considered using it for your application? You can still make plain SQL queries through it, and it handles your pooling and caching for you.

Comment: @mlaverd paragraph 3 - I slightly modified my question to give further explanation what "shared among apps" means

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a J2EE application server then consider building a component implementing the Java Connector Architecture ([JCA](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/connector/)). Each instance of the component accesses a single Session and you configure the container to create at most five (from your example) instances. The container manages the pool and the component's lifecycle. Additionally, all applications deployed on that application server share the component's pool.

If I remember correctly (its been a while) there is also a way to signal the container that an instance died. In this scenario, the container removes the dead instance and instantiates a new one.

Some non-J2EE application servers have support for JCA components so check into it even if you are not using a traditional J2EE container.

Comment: JCA does indeed support pooling, but is meant for inbound/outbound connectivity. IMO, if you just want pooling, it's a bit overkill.

Comment: The question mentions managing a pool of sessions provided by an external system and shared across independent applications. Requirements like this typically arise when something like licensing limits the number of connections from a single source such as a box or CPU.

Comment: You are actually very right. JCA may then be appropriate. It would also solve Classloader issue if the pool is shared for different web apps. (I had up voted you answer anyway).